# Valid operations to the value of a matrix game

Tags: game-theory

Suppose I have a 2-player zero-sum matrix game with the payoff matrix

$U = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, I can express the value of the game as

$v = value(\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix})$.

How do I know which operations I am allowed to use on this equation? For example, I read that I can add a constant to the value and then to all elements of $U$:

$v = value(\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}) \Leftrightarrow v + \delta = value(\begin{pmatrix}
a + \delta & b + \delta \\
c + \delta & d + \delta 
\end{pmatrix})$

Or that I could do the same with multiplication:

$v = value(\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}) \Leftrightarrow v \alpha = value(\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha a & \alpha b \\
\alpha c & \alpha d
\end{pmatrix})$

Why is that, and are there further valid operations I can apply to both sides to obtain equivalent equations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope! These are the only ones. This is because utility function is an affine multivariable function...

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the link/term I've been missing when trying to find out why this holds!

Comment: Don't mention it!!!